# How integrate themeSwitcher in a menubar with primefaces?

Tags: primefaces, themes

Is it possible to use or integrate **themeSwitcher** in a **menubar**

My idea is to transform this :

```
<p:themeSwitcher id="basic" value="#{themeSwitcherView.theme}" style="width:165px">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Choose Theme" itemValue="" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{themeSwitcherView.themes}" />
    <p:ajax listener="#{themeSwitcherView.saveTheme}" />
</p:themeSwitcher>
```

and

```
public void saveTheme(AjaxBehaviorEvent ajax) {   
    setTheme((String) ((ThemeSwitcher)ajax.getSource()).getValue());
}
```

to that (begining of solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47064923/mixing-static-and-dynamic-menu-entries-in-primefaces-menu-components)

```
<p:submenu label="Theme" >
     <c:forEach items="#{themeSwitcherView.themes}" var="item">                           
         <p:menuitem value="#{item}" actionListener="#{themeSwitcherView.saveTheme}" />
    </c:forEach>
</p:submenu>
```

but don't work, I get the list but no action made !

thank you

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mvce] and improve your question! We are not people that should write code for you... for free

Comment: [mvce] should have been \[mcve\], [mcve] ;-)

Comment: ok, I have change my post ! And delete my pesodo answer :-)

Comment: All reasons for 'No action made' are in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandbutton-commandlink-ajax-action-listener-method-not-invoked-or-input-value

Comment: I change `actionListener="#{themeSwitcherView.saveTheme(item)` and `public void saveTheme(String theme)`. But, I can't set **theme** for session or context ?

Comment: the change take effect after changing page

Comment: Then update the page (update="@all" somewhere, or do a full refresh of the page...).